# can I use HTML templates in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-template

I am very new in Joomla.I have to create one simple static applicatin in joomla.Can I use my HTML templates or joomla temlates are diffrent?Where we use `PHP` in joomla?From where I have to start?means whether I have to create html template first and then move it to joomla `OR` have to create page template in joomla itself?

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance, you might find it easier to build your static webpage and then create your Joomla template. You can then go through your static HTML and place the calls to the joomla modules and components.